# How do I set and save a random password for the MySQL/MariaDB root user using Ansible?

Tags: mysql, ansible, mariadb

How do I use Ansible to set a random (32 character alphanumeric) root password for a MariaDB / MySQL database and save it to the `~/.my.cnf` file (to allow commands to find this password)?

It should only configure it once, and not change the password every time if the playbook is run multiple times.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43415961/1837991) uses a password from a variable.

If I use this, it changes the password every time that the playbook is run: (and it fails to save the password - if the playbook is interrupted after this task, the password is lost)

```
- name: "Change database root user password"
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ lookup('password','/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits length=32') }}"
    host: "{{ item }}"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    state: present
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False
  with_items:
  - localhost
  - "::1"
  - 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: (It feels like this belongs on Server fault, but [meta disagrees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294923/are-ansible-puppet-chef-salt-questions-on-topic))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some assumptions:

- The root user is sufficiently covered by `'root'@'localhost'` and other local root users needs to be removed
- The tasks need to be failure tolerant. If interrupted, it should be possible to run again, as far as reasonably possible
- The Ansible tasks runs as root - `~/.my.cnf` expands to `/root/.my.cnf`
- Everything else that needs the password can get it from `~/.my.cnf` (All the normal tools does, as long as they run as the right user, `root` in this case)

Overview:

- This generates the root password using [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/password.html)
- It saves it to `~/.my.cnf.new` (To ensure it is available on the server before it is set. This allows for (manual) recovery if it is interrupted)
- It sets the password in the database
- It renames the file ([replicating `mv`'s functionality in two tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210853/1837991) - a hardlink and delete) (`link` and `unlink`)
- It cleans up any other equivalent users, like `'root'@'127.0.0.1'`, `'root'@'::1'`, `'root'@'<hostname>'` (Using a few facts to ensure that most possibilities are hit)

Template for password config: ('templates/my_passwd.cnf.j2' relative to the role directory)

```
[client]
user={{ item.user }}
password={{ item.password }}
```

Tasks:

```
# MariaDB: Set up secure root password
# Set up (and save) secure root password
# Check for /root/.my.cnf
# All the other things are skipped if this file already exists
- name: "Check if we already have a root password config"
  stat:
    path: /root/.my.cnf
  register: mysql_root_result

# Generate password
# This uses https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/password.html
# to generate a 32 character random alphanumeric password
- name: "Generate database root password if needed"
  set_fact:
    mysql_root_passwd: "{{ lookup('password','/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits length=32') }}"
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False

# Generate /root/.my.cnf.new
# A temporary file is used to keep it from breaking further commands
# It also ensures that the password is on the server if the critical
# parts are interrupted
- name: "Save new root password in temporary file"
  template:
    src: my_passwd.cnf.j2
    dest: /root/.my.cnf.new
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0400
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False
  with_items:
  - user: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_passwd }}"

# START of area that you don't want to interrupt
# If this is interrupted after the first task
# it can be fixed by manually running this on the server
# mv /root/.my.cnf.new /root/.my.cnf
# If the playbook is reran before that. The password would be lost!
# Add DB user
- name: "Add database root user"
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_passwd }}"
    host: "{{ item }}"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    state: present
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False
  with_items:
  - localhost

# Now move the config in place
- name: "Rename config with root password to correct name - Step 1 - link"
  file:
    state: hard
    src: /root/.my.cnf.new
    dest: /root/.my.cnf
    force: yes
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False
# END of area that you don't want to interrupt

# Interrupting before this task will leave a temporary file around
# Everything will work as it should though
- name: "Rename config with root password to correct name - Step 2 - unlink"
  file:
    state: absent
    path: /root/.my.cnf.new
  when: mysql_root_result.stat.exists == False

# Remove additional root users - these don't have the password set
# You might want to ensure that none of these variables are `localhost`
# All return somewhat different values on my test system
- name: "Clean up additional root users"
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    host: "{{ item }}"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    state: absent
  with_items:
  - "::1"
  - 127.0.0.1
  - "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
  - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```